# How to open an url(web view) in modal in angular 5

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog

My requirement is to show a modal(dialog box) on click of a button and load an url in that modal. It should have a close button also.I have been using modal for showing alert messages but couldnot open an url in that. Need the javascript or html code for the same.

Comment: Tried this with iframe but getting this error while loading the url Refused to display 'https://......' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  iframe 
.Put it into modal body

```
<iframe src="pdf.pdf" style="position: relative;   top: 0;  bottom: 0; left: 0;   width: 100%;   height: 100%;  border: 0"></iframe>
```